# Problems with OleDbConnection when opening a c# form with command prompt or hyperlink, but not Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, shortcut

I have a c# program which does the following on form load:

1. Creates an OleDbConnection to a database in the same folder as the program
2. Gets the computer name
3. Gets the username
4. Fills in some textbox fields on the form with data obtained from the database

When I open the form using Windows explorer, shortcut, or debugging in visual studio express 2013, it does all of this without any issues.  When trying to open it with a command prompt or with a hyperlink, the database connection is not established, but no error messages appear.  The textbox fields are filled with "not found" as a result of my try-catch statements around the oledb commands.  The same try-catch statement should print ex.message to a text file, but that does not happen either.  As stated before, this all runs flawlessly when running from debug mode in vs or running the program by opening it in Windows explorer, so I'm not sure how to debug this.

2 questions - Is there a known problem with opening c# forms which try to establish OleDb connections with access databases on form load when launching the program from command prompt or a shortcut?  If so, are there any workarounds?  Given that it runs fine in debug mode in vs, and my catch statements seem to be terminating prematurely without error messages, is there any other way to debug and find out exactly where the problem occurs?

I left off some of the irrelevant lines of code to make this shorter.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userData = onLoad.loadDb(out userNotFound);
    ComputerName = onLoad.getComputer();

    // Session Notification
    WTSRegisterSessionNotification(this.Handle, NotifyForThisSession);

    // Initialize Hooks
    initialize_Hooks();

    if (userData.Count < 4)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) { userData.Add("Not Found"); }
    }
    // globals:
    FullID = userData[0];
    ID = userData[2];
    firstName = userData[1];
    lastName = userData[0];
    nanid = userData[3];
    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

    // Fill in Form
    label1.Text = fullName;
    label2.Text = ID;
    label3.Text = nanid;
}
public class onLoad
{
    public static string getUser() // returns Environment.UserName
    public static string getComputer() // returns System.Environment.MachineName;
    public static List<string> loadDb(out bool userNotFound)
    {
        List<string> rList = new List<string>();
        string strAccessConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
        string strAccessSelect = "SELECT (//select statement which works fine when I open the program in explorer or vs debug)
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;
        try
        {
            myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) { rList.Add("Not Found"); }
            error_handler.error_logger(ex.Message);
            userNotFound = true;
            return rList;
        }
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
            myAccessConn.Open();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet,"table1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error_handler.error_logger(ex.Message);
            userNotFound = true;
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) { rList.Add("Not Found"); }
            return rList;
        }
        finally
        {
              myAccessConn.Close();
        }
        try
        {
            DataRowCollection dra = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
            {
                code that conditions the data, works fine when running the program
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string returnString = ex.Message;
            error_handler.error_logger(ex.Message);
            userNotFound = true;
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) { rList.Add("Not Found"); }
            return rList;
        }
        return rList;

    }
}
class error_handler
{
    public static string filename = "error.txt";
    public static void error_logger(string error_message)
    {
        error_message = onLoad.getUser() + "\t" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss") + "\t" + onLoad.getComputer() + "\t" + "Error: " + error_message; 
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        //writes error_message to a new text file or appends if it already exists. works fine when running from windows explorer or vs debug
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably has do to with the current or working directory not being set to what you think it is. How are you setting the path to the db?

Comment: Currently, the program executable is in the same directory as the database, both located on a server.  The connection string says Source=db.mdb, so I guess it's just a relative path.  I will investigate whether it makes a difference if i put the absolute path for the database and the error text file.

Comment: It now works fine with hyperlink, but it still has the same problem when trying to launch from command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that shortcut passes in the working directory as a parameter. The documentation for [File.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) states that when using a relative path the relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory.

You can use the [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) function to determine if the path is set correctly.

If you are using files that you know are going to be in a path relative to the application I would use Application's path or at least set `Environment.CurrentDirectory` = Application's path.

Also take a look at the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0].` That is probally being set by the shortcut.